# sklearn error - ValueError: bad input shape (330, 5)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Trying to fit a logistic regression model but receiving the below error:

> ValueError: bad input shape (330, 5)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = ad_data[['Daily Time Spent on Site','Age','Area Income','Daily Internet Usage','Male']]
y= ad_data['Clicked on Ad']

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.33,random_state=42)

logmodel = LogisticRegression()
logmodel.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: provide complete error message and shape of  `X` and `y`

Answer (score 2):

The error is not very verbose, but I think you should assign `train_test_split` it this way:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.33,random_state=42)
```

refer to: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: yeah  here is the screenshot

Comment: the given link hasn't given any useful answers, any other suggestions? Do I need to reshape X_train and y_train?

Comment: Have you changed the order of your variable assignment? How did the error message change?